# PHP settings in apache2 config file completely ignored

Tags: linux, debian, apache-2.4, virtualhost, php7

On a fresh Debian 9 install, I installed PHP 7.2 and Apache2.

php has been installed from the Sury repo with these extensions:

```
php7.2-mysql php7.2-dom php7.2-simplexml php7.2-ssh2 php7.2-xml php7.2-xmlreader php7.2-curl  php7.2-exif php7.2-gd  php7.2-iconv php7.2-imagick php7.2-json  php7.2-mbstring php7.2-posix php7.2-sockets php7.2-tokenizer php7.2-soap php7.2-intl php7.2-mbstring
```

everything seem to be working fine I even managed to install wordpress on the server, however if I try to ovrride the php.ini configs in the virtualhost config for Apache2 they are not overridden no matter where I put them in the file, I tried in and outside the Directory tag and I tried php_admin_value, php_value, php_flag and php_admin_flag. None of them is working and I'm not sure what to do to solve this. I need to override the open_basedir settings because I need to host multiple websites on the same server, so it's very important for its security.

Loaded modules from php info:

```
core mod_so mod_watchdog http_core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version mod_unixd mod_access_compat mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_filter mod_headers mod_mime prefork mod_negotiation mod_php7 mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_status


Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

Additional .ini files parsed:

```
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/15-xml.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-dom.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-imagick.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-intl.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-soap.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-ssh2.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-wddx.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
```

.

```
Server Root /etc/apache2
```

Strangely enough the php info page returns DOCUMENT_ROOT and CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT as /var/www/html even though my virtual host's root is /var/www/html//

```
ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
000-default.conf  <mydomain>.conf
```

.

```
ls /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
charset.conf                other-vhosts-access-log.conf
localized-error-pages.conf  security.conf
```

.

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
access_compat.load  autoindex.conf  mime.conf         reqtimeout.load
alias.conf          autoindex.load  mime.load         rewrite.load
alias.load          deflate.conf    mpm_prefork.conf  setenvif.conf
auth_basic.load     deflate.load    mpm_prefork.load  setenvif.load
authn_core.load     dir.conf        negotiation.conf  status.conf
authn_file.load     dir.load        negotiation.load  status.load
authz_core.load     env.load        php7.2.conf
authz_host.load     filter.load     php7.2.load
authz_user.load     headers.load    reqtimeout.conf
```

.

mydomain.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t$
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName <mydomain>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/<mydomain>
        DirectoryIndex index.html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/<mydomain>_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/<mydomain>_access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        <Directory /var/www/html/<mydomain>>
                AllowOverride All
                Require host <mydomain>
                php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/html/<mydomain>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

.

unfortunately I can't post my php.ini file as it's too long.

Some help would be much appreciated as this seems to be like a mystery to solve and it's very important for the server security.

Comment: you could strip out all comments from the files if they are too long. ie.: `grep -Ev '^\s*#' mydomain.conf`

Comment: please add the output of `apachectl -S` so we can see if the vhost is recognized correctly.
also you can use a pastebin and put the link here if some output is too long.

Comment: as a first hunch I would guess your `000-default.conf`and the `mydomain.conf` overlap, so the first one wins?

Comment: did you figure this out?